# PHP Why does my select option show empty

Tags: php

When I submit the form I don't get the value of the select option I tried using POST and session but it always show nothing

### main.php

```
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="test.php"> 


      <?php if($id == 1 OR $id==2){ 
      echo" <p> No data</p> ";}else{
      ?>
      <select class="form-control" name="data">  
<?php 
                  $getdata = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data";
                     $data = mysqli_query($conn,$getdata ) 
              or die(mysqli_error());
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $data )) {
$dataName = $row['data_name']; 

echo '<option value="'.$row['data_id'].'">'.$dataName.'</option>';
                 $_SESSION['data_id']= $data_id;

} 
 ?>

 </select>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">show</button>


 </form>
```

### test.php

```
  $dataID = isset($_POST['data_id']) ? $_POST['data_id'] : '';
echo "data is $dataID";
```

Comment: Its working fine if you change it to $_POST['data'] where you still facing issue dont getting.

Comment: Have you checked your $row containing $row['data_id'] or not. Please check option value filled up or not and try to put static value in <option> and check.

Comment: @RuchishParikh I tried and changed it to data and followed @ dhara but I still get nothing I only get the string "data is"

Comment: try this <option value="test"> and check

Comment: @RuchishParikh thank you it worked I checked the option value and the error occurred because of spelling mistake

Comment: where is the closing of else statement?

Answer (score 1):

Name of your input type select is `data` and you are accessing it with `data_id` so you have to use `$_POST['data']` instead of `$_POST['data_id']`

Answer (score 0):

get value of select box using name "data" as you have set `name="data"`  in `<select>` box in html:

```
$dataID = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '';
echo "data is".$dataID;
```

Comment: I changed it to data but I still get nothing I only get data is

Answer (score 0):

**main.php**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="test.php"> 
<?php 
if($id == 1 OR $id==2)
{
    echo" <p> No data</p> ";
}
else
{
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="data">  
        <?php 
        $getdata = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data";
        $data = mysqli_query($conn,$getdata ) or die(mysqli_error());
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $data ))
        {
            $dataName = $row['data_name']; 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['data_id'].'">'.$dataName.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
} 
?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">show</button>
```

**test.php**

```
 $dataID = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '';

echo "data is $dataID";
```

try this one..

Answer (score 0):

Check below points its may be creating issue.

- Check first your `<select class="form-control" name="data">` name is `data` so you can access it using `$_POST['data']` not `data_id`.
- Check for `<option value="'.$row['data_id'].'">` may be data_id not giving correct value try to check with static value.

Comment: Try above points and accept the answer if its useful to you. @uglyduck

Answer (score 0):

I modified this code for you,please use this code.Its work for me,i hope this code will work also for you.

### main.php

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" action="test.php"> 
  <?php
  if($id == 1 OR $id==2)
  { 
      echo" <p> No data</p> ";
  }
  else
  {
  ?>
  <select class="form-control" name="data">  
  <?php
  $getdata = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data";
  $data = mysqli_query($conn,$getdata ) or die(mysqli_error());
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $data ))
  {
 $dataName = $row['data_name'];
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['data_id']; ?>"><?php echo $dataName ?></option>
  $_SESSION['data_id']= $row['data_id'];
  <?php
  }
  } 
  ?>

  </select>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">show</button>


 </form>
```

### test.php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
 echo $_POST['data'];
}
?>
```